# Can two threads share the same JPA transaction?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, openjpa

I am writing an integration test in `JUnit` for a Message Driven Pojo (MDP):

```
@JmsListener(destination = "jms/Queue", containerFactory = "cf")
public void processMessage(TextMessage message) throws JMSException {
    repo.save(new Entity("ID"));
}
```

where `repo` is a `spring-data` repository

my unit test:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    //sendMsg
    sendJMSMessage();
    //verify DB state
    Entity e = repo.findOne("ID");
    assertThat(e, is(notNullValue()) );
}
```

Now, the thing is that the `processMessage()` method is executed in a different thread than the `test()` method, so I figured out that I need to somehow wait for the `processMessage()` method to complete before verifying the state of the DB. The best solution I could find was based on CountDownLatch. so now the methods look like this:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "jms/Queue", containerFactory = "cf")
public void processMessage(TextMessage message) throws JMSException {
    repo.save(new Entity("ID"));
    latch.countDown();
}
```

and the test

```
@Test
public void test() {
    //set the countdownlatch
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    JMSProcessor.setLatch(latch);
    //sendMsg
    sendJMSMessage();
     try {
        countDownLatch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    //verify DB state
    Entity e = repo.findOne("ID");
    assertThat(e, is(notNullValue()) );
}
```

So I was very proud of myself and then I run the test and it failed. The `repo.findOne("ID")` returned `null`. In the first reaction I set up a breakpoint at that line and proceed with debugging. During the debugging session the `repo.findOne("ID")` actually returned the entity inserted by the `@JMSListener`listener method.

After scratching my head for a while here's the current theory: Since the `spring-data` repository is accessed in two different threads, it gets two different instances of `EntityManager` and therefore the two threads are in a differen't transaction. Eventhough there's some sort of synchronization using the `CountDownLatch`, the transaction bound to the thread executing the `@JMSListener` annotated method has not committed yet when the JUnit `@Test` annotated method starts a new transaction and tries to retrieve the entity.

So my question is:

1. Is there a way for one thread to wait for the commit of the other.
2. Can two threads share one transaction in such a synchronized context (ie, the two threads would not access the `EntityManager` simultaneously)
3. Is my testing approach a nonsense and there is a better way of doing this

Comment: I don't see the code for `sendJMSMessage()` but I would expect that when you send a message, you will at least want an "OK" response and you will have to wait for that response. Once you have that response, the message should be stored and the transaction completed.

Comment: No, you wouldn't want an 'OK' response in a fire-and-forget type of JMS messaging. And it's kind of irrelevant to the question anyway.